# stopPropagation() in situation in which there no need to bubble up the event but also doesn't hurt to do so?

Tags: jquery

When writing jQuery event handlers, I often encounter situation in which there no need to bubble up the event but also doesn't hurt to do so. Do developers usually call stopPropagation() in this situation?

Answer (score 0):

Not really. When you notice that something is being triggered by event bubbling and that behaviour is unwanted then take action. As a side-note, you can prevent propagation when programmatically triggering event handlers by using `.triggerHandler("click")` for instance.

Comment: I am kinda confused. You said "not really" but also told me to take action. What do you mean by taking action?

Say, I want to capture clicks on a thumbnail and then display its original image. I would bind an event handler, that displays the original image, to the thumbnail's click event. In this same handler, should I include stopPropagation() to stop event bubbling? But then, there's no undesired behaviour even with the event bubbling all the way to the top.